# I'm stuck on a trig substitution problem and am absolutely lost.

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

The problem is 
$\int{\sqrt{9x^2+25}\over x}dx$

Right now I've got to this point with all my work:

$x=a\tan\theta$

$3x=5\tan\theta$

$dx={5\over 3} {\sec^2\theta}d\theta$

$$\int{\sqrt{5\tan\theta^2+5}{5\over 3} {\sec^2\theta}\over {5 \over 3}\tan\theta}$$

$$\int{\sqrt{25\tan\theta^2+5}{5 \over 3}{\sec\theta^2}\over{5 \over 3}\tan\theta}$$

$$\int{\sqrt{5(\tan\theta^2+1)}{5 \over 3}{\sec\theta^2}\over{5 \over 3}\tan\theta}$$

For the life of me I can't seem to figure out what to do after this, I've been stuck on how to move on from here. I'm practicing only Trig Sub, so if there's another way, whether hyperbolic route, or an easier route, I'd rather do it with trig sub just for the practice.

Comment: You should have $\sqrt{25\tan^2\theta + 25}$.  How did that $25$ become a $5$?

Answer (score 1):

First, let's substitute:

$$u= \sqrt{9x^2 + 25}$$

The integral will become:

$$\int \frac{u^2}{u^2-25} du$$
$$= 25 \int \frac{1}{u^2-25} du + \int 1 du $$
$$= 25 (\int \frac{1}{10(u-5)} du -  \int \frac{1}{10(u+5)} du)  + u$$
$$= \frac{5}{2} (\int \frac{1}{u-5} du -  \int \frac{1}{u+5} du) + u$$

Integrating $\frac{1}{u-5}$ and $\frac{1}{u+5}$ and you get:

$$\int \frac{1}{u-5} du = ln(u-5), \int \frac{1}{u+5} du = ln(u+5)$$

So the result will be:

$$\frac{5}{2} (ln(u-5) - ln(u+5)) + u$$

Undo substitution and you get the final answer.

Answer (score 0):

For $t\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ by your work we need to evaluate $$5\int\frac{1}{\cos^2t\sin{t}}dt=-5\int\frac{1}{\cos^2t(1-\cos^2t)}d(\cos{t}).$$
Can you end it now?

Answer (score 0):

The whole point to trig substitution is that square roots and addition don't get along well.  This is a technique for getting that pesky plus (or minus) sign out of the square root.

After you fix the little problem with the $5$, then just use the identity $\tan^2 \theta +1 = \sec^2 \theta.$  Then the square root won't be a problem.  Ignoring the constants your integral becomes

$$\int \frac{\sec^3 \theta}{\tan \theta} \; d\theta.$$

I would multiply top and bottom by $\tan \theta$, change the denominator to $\sec^2 \theta -1$ and substitute $u = \sec \theta$.
Then you should get

$$\int \frac{u^2}{u^2-1}\; du.$$

If I did the constants in my head right, there should be a $5$ out front.